# How to get id's of all the birthday posts in facebook through graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get id's of all the posts of birthday wishes on my timeline. When I am using graph api and sending request for *me/feed* all birthday posts are not showing instead there is only one node that has a story **xyz and 205 others wrote on your timeline** . If I take id of this node and send request it is only the post of the last person **xyz** in this case. How can I expand all the 206 posts to get their id's ?

Comment: This isn't possible with Facebook Graph API. Facebook clumps birthday posts.

Comment: Any other method to get their id's ?